# How to highlight text in TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I highlight some portion of the text in TextArea? For example I have start and end position of the text and I need change its background color to yellow. How can I do this using  jQuery or simple JavaScript?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately the `textarea` element is plain text only. You'll need to use a WYSIWYG editor like FCKeditor or TinyMCE (or roll your own widget based on a `div` with `designmode` or `contenteditable` if you only need highlighting). [This](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/778165.aspx) might help you along. Good luck!